# How to import a .tff font from resources and draw a string on the screen using Graphics2D?

Tags: java

I made a new TrueType Font, and I want to use it to draw a String on my JPanel. This does not seem to work:

```
Font f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/res/myFont.ttf"));
f = f.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 20);
g2d.setFont(f);
g2d.drawString(x, y, "my string");
```

What should I do?

Comment: Use `g2d.setFont(f);` **before** you use the **drawString()** method.

Comment: Oh yes, I did that, But forgot to mention here! sorry! Thanks for the mention

Comment: You're not showing enough. Where and how are you using this code?

Comment: I am using this in my game, to draw a Congratulation on screen, but I want to have another font style instead of the regular fonts. EDIT: Where should I paste the code so that you can see it?